# Braess's Paradox in Electrical Circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

["Paradoxical behaviour of mechanical and electrical networks"](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v352/n6337/abs/352699a0.html) [1] states that adding a current-carrying path can increase the voltage drop across a circuit. What is the simplest example of a circuit (preferably consisting solely of two-terminal devices) that exhibits such behavior?

```
[1] Cohen, Joel E., and Paul Horowitz. "Paradoxical behaviour of mechanical and electrical networks." Nature 352.6337 (1991): 699-701.
```

Comment: You might want to try a Wheatstone bridge type of circuit with two non-linear elements.

Comment: @Johannes what kind of non-linear elements are you talking about?

Comment: Have a look at this paper: http://www.rockefeller.edu/labheads/cohenje/PDFs/185CohenHorowitzNature1991.pdf

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for! I was wondering whether it was possible to construct such a circuit using only (ohmic) resistors, but I guess it's not possible.

Comment: Indeed, it’s impossible using only ohmic resistors; this result is called Rayleigh’s monotonicity theorem.

Comment: The link provided by Johannes is broken; https://lab.rockefeller.edu/cohenje/assets/file/185CohenHorowitzNature1991.pdf is an updated version of the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple circuit that demonstrates Braess's Paradox.  If the red switch is open, 1.5 Amps will flow from the power source to the ground.  If the red switch is closed, ADDING A CONDUCTOR to the circuit, the current DROPS to 1.0 Amp.

[image: A simple circuit that demonstrates Braess's Paradox.]

When the switch is closed, no current flows through the Zener diodes.

Comment: Nice example, and welcome to Phys.SE!